# popuplating the list view with pictures from external phone memory in android

Tags: java, android, listview, storage

Its Getting the images from the string file in values but i want to direct it to collect from Phone memory. any help?

MainActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                //Create intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

                //Start details activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {

        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }
        return imageItems;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            ImageItem.setImageURI(selectedImage);

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get to the root of external storage (which, on some devices, is an SD card). List all the files looking for your images on your device